# How to backpropagate transposed convolution?

Tags: cnn, backpropagation

I'm currently learning Convolutional Neural Networks and am stuck on trying to figure out how to compute gradients in a layer that uses transposed convolution. Also, how do I calculate the gradients if I use padding=1 and stride=2?

Thanks to this article "https://hideyukiinada.github.io/cnn_backprop_strides2.html" I was able to figure out how to calculate gradients in normal convolution and all that remains for me is to figure out how to calculate them in transposed convolution.